# Geometry-based material without UV or vertex paint

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to create a (Cycles) material that's based on geometry without doing any UV unwrapping or vertex painting:

[image]

I'd like to created a map based on depth into the brain folds to control the glowiness. Are there any nodes or workflows that could let me achieve this?

**EDIT:** [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking for an approach which avoids manually unwrapping/vertex painting, maybe the end result is more important than how you get there. For this spherical shape trigonometry offers a solution.

**Nodes Approach**

[image]

This approach uses the spherical property of the object. There's a relationship between the point's normal and it's normalized position: when the point normal faces outward it's closer to the normalized position of that point.

[image]

[image]

Replacing the Diffuse shader Node with a Translucent shader in this .blend also gives interesting results.

Comment: Very clever! I love it!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the pointiness output of the *[Geometry](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html#geometry)* node to get an approximate cavity map. You will need a *ColorRamp* node to adjust the range, so that it fits your model.

Then use that as a mix factor, or mask for the rest of your shader.

[image: cycles material nodes]

Comment: Good idea.. doesn't work for my model though (see my edit for my .blend). I can imagine something like "distance from convex hull?"

Comment: So dirty vertex colors is not an option? Is that because it is a bulk operation?

Comment: Dirty vertex colours might be OK actually, as long as it can be completely procedural. I have a pile of different brain models, so I'd like to be able to script this effect.