# Can a texture be baked to an object that doesn't have a UV map?

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I have a object like this that I'm animating with shape keys:

[image]

I have a material on the basis object, based on its geometry:

[image]

Is it possible to bake the output from the color ramp node onto the basis vertices? I'd like those values to follow through the animation, rather than recalculating the geometry at each frame.

Comment: In Blender Internal there's an option to bake to vertex colors, but you'll have to rebuild your node setup for that render engine. Could you tell what are you doing with the two vector math nodes? I'm not sure to fully understand what's going on. I mean...if you change object location, the whole map change? Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: It's a way to identify the internal foldy bits (from this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41894/822). It's essentially comparing the mesh normal to its normalized position; in other words, is my normal pointing the same way as a line to me from my origin?  The procedure is more important to me than the outcome though.. I'd like to get some arbitrary cycles values baked onto the mesh so I can visualize how they move around with the shape keys.